# bash dropbox-uploader from anywhere

Tags: bash

Just installed bash dropbox-upload on my raspberry Pi with a debian distro.
Right now I have to be in my root/src/Dropbox-Upload/ catalog to run ./dropbox-upload.sh command.

How can I make ./dropbox-upload.sh run from anywhere?

I saw something like Add: export PATH=$PATH:/new/path

But I'm really a newbie on linux and scripting. Where and how should I add it?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

In your home directory there should be a file like .profile / .bash_profile / .bashrc 
If one of these files is present, open them and see if there is a line already defining your PATH. If so, you could append the folder containing the dropbox upload shell script. If not, create a new line for PATH.

More info on path cam be found here: http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/11.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing with your `PATH` you could simply move it to `/usr/local/bin` (assuming this directory exists and is already on the default `PATH`, and assuming the script is self-contained, i.e. doesn't also need to have libraries or data files installed).

The prefix `./` is used to refer to the current directory; you should omit that part to make the shell use your `PATH` for locating the script or executable.